# Why can I not log into the chat room?

Tags: support, chat

I am quite hesitant to post here, but as of today I can't log into the TeX SE chat room. I can log into the main site just fine but when I attempt to enter the chat room I get a reminder that I must have 100 reputation points, which obviously I have. When I attempt to "complete the login" by clicking at the bottom of the page I get a stalled page that doesn't do anything. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: Weird: one for the Staff I think - use the Help link to contact them

Comment: It seems to be working now. I have no idea what the glitch was.

Comment: This was also mentioned in the Tavern https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9766524#9766524

Comment: Thank you. I tacitly assumed I had been banned or suspended.

Answer (score 4):

The problem was apparently a known transient issue and has been resolved.